# Laravel syncing multiple relations plus pivot data excluding empty data

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation, `Recipes` and `Ingredients`. I am trying to sync multiple `ingredients` to a `recipe`. I have an edit form where I send a `recipe` and a list of all `ingredients`.

In my `ingredient_recipe` table I have two extra pivot columns, `number1` and `number2`.

In my form I have two dropdowns, simplified below:

```
<select name="{{ $ingredient->id }}[number1]">
    <option></option> // Empty value
    <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
    <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
</select>

<select name="{{ $ingredient->id }}[number2]">
    <option></option> // Empty value
    <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
    <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
</select>
```

When submitting the form, I get the following results:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "number1" => example1
    "number2" => example2
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "number1" => example2
    "number2" => example1
  ]
]
```

In my controller's `update` method I am doing the following to sync the ingredients to the recipe:

```
$recipe->ingredients()->sync($ingredients);
```

Where `$ingredients` is the output of the request posted above.

While this does work flawlessly, it also syncs the values that have no selection in the dropdowns, because the `$ingredient->id` will always be submitted.

I have two questions about how I am approaching this.

1. My main question is, how to avoid that ingredients with empty dropdown values get synced?
2. It seems like a wrong solution to what I want to achieve I think, if so, any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is the following:

```
foreach($ingredients as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_null($value['number1']) || is_null($value['number2']))
    {
        unset($ingredients[$key]);
    }
}
```

This checks if either `number1` or `number2` is empty and if so, it removes the whole ingredient from the array so only selected values will be synced.